# PHP VLookup (conditional match) Alternative?

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

How do I return the results for the provision_id column so that they are conditional on contracts.id for each row? Right now, I get the same result on every row. The desired effect is sort of like VLookup in Excel.  Not sure how to use if else/sql values to achieve it in PHP though.

Relevant code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$contents = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, name, remaining, contract_value FROM salaries"));
$contracts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT contracts.id,source,provision,provision_id FROM contracts LEFT JOIN salaries ON contracts.id = salaries.id"));

 ?>

   [table header stuff...]
```

```
foreach ($contents as $content) {
    ?>   
         <tr>
                <td><?php echo $content->name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $content->remaining ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $content->contract_value ?></td>
                <td><?php foreach ($contracts as $contract) { echo $contract->provision_id }; ?> 
               </td>
```

Current Output

```
Name               Remaining         Contract_Value    Provision_ID
--------------     ---------------   --------------    --------------
Adam               100               300               A1 B1 C1
Bill               200               400               A1 B1 C1
Chad               200               400               A1 B1 C1
```

Desired Output

```
Name               Remaining         Contract_Value    Provision_ID
--------------     ---------------   --------------    --------------
Adam               100               300               A1
Bill               200               400               B1
Chad               200               400               C1
```

where A1,B1,C1 each represent a stored data cell that corresponds to the name of the person in column1.  I am trying to make provision_id conditional based on Adam, Bill, and Chad's IDs, not names, though I don't want the ID to be shown in the php output.

Essentially, I want PHP to "lookup" the ID (aka member id) and print the corresponding provision_id. Joining tables probably won't work in this case as I'm also pulling "tooltips" from the table as a mouseover effect on A1, B1, C1, etc.

APPENDIX 1 - aka what has also been happening. I failed to explain (in my attempt to keep it simple) that Adam Bill and Chad each have more than one provision ID. Adam has provision IDs: A1, A2, and A3 for example.  I am trying to avoid the problem (GROUP_CONCAT could work but I dont think it does because I have a mouseover tooltip for each provision) below.

```
Name               Remaining         Contract_Value    Provision_ID
--------------     ---------------   --------------    --------------
Adam               100               300               A1
Adam               100               300               A2
Adam               100               300               A3
Bill               200               400               B1
Bill               200               400               B2
Chad               200               400               C1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you explain how the rows should look?

Comment: I updated the question to show what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query.  Then, you can do it all with one request to the database.

```
SELECT salaries.id AS salaries_id, salaries.name, salaries.remaining, 
salaries.contract_value, contracts.provision_id AS provision_id 
FROM salaries LEFT JOIN contracts ON contracts.id=salaries.id
```

Comment: You're dead-on though I left out one important thing. Provision_id is a null field in which some people do not yet have contract provisions. This query did not return those people w/o provisions. There's probably a conditional null workaround to that though I am learning as I go so if you know how to tweak, please let me know. In in the meantime, I'll seek out the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe I mean to say that it is pulling only people that have ids in both tables. the contracts table is very incomplete at this point.

Comment: I just edited the SQL to make it a LEFT JOIN like you had in your original question.  That should get all entries in the salaries table.

Comment: So sorry. I think I'm turning delirious after all of this time spent. I have multiple contract provision_ids for each person, each id representing a clause in the contract. Each clause has its own row in contracts table. I was mistaken when saying you were right on before because that solution prints a duplicate row for each person that has more than one provision.  I have edited my question w/ Appendix 1 to show what is now happening.

Comment: I now put everything online: http://beerlyrics.com/jimmy-jones/

Trying to get that 1,2 into just JD Drew's row. Now you can see what I'm really up to :/

Answer (score 0):

Had to seek professional help for this as I'm still self-teaching. He used a technique called conditional shorthand which made it so that $contracts query only went to work for the rows in which 'id' matched between the two tables.

Winning code snippet:

```
     foreach ($contracts as $contract)
                    {
                        echo ( $content->id == $contract->id ) ?
                             '<a href="' . $contract->source . '" tooltip="' . $contract->provision . '">' . $contract->provision_id . " " . '</a>' : '';
                     } 
                   ?>
                </td>

<?php };
```

He sent me this link: http://www.bradino.com/php/ternary-operator-conditional/
You can find him at http://travisballard.com/.

Cheers!